# React: uncontrolled/controlled input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, react-hooks

I'm learning React and I created a really simple "shopping list app". Everything is working now but I'm getting this error: "Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component".

Here it is my code:

```
function InputArea(props) {

    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState({
       inputText: {text: ""}
    });

    function handleChange(event){
        setInputText(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleClick(event) {
        props.onSubmit(inputText);
        setInputText({text: ""});
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    return(
             <div className="input-group w-50">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    onChange={handleChange} 
                    ariadescribedby="button-addon" 
                    value={inputText.text} 
                    placeholder="Insert Item">
                </input>
            <div className="input-group-append">
                <Button
                    id="button-addon"
                    color="dark"
                    style={{marginBottom: "2rem"}} 
                    onClick={handleClick}>Add Item
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The problem appears when I want to reset my input, in order to see the placeholder instead of the name of the last item added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in how you are updating state, how you use the state and how you initialise it.

With hooks unlike `setState` in classes, the values of state updater are not merged but replaced and when you run

```
setInputText({text: ""});
```

your inputText is replaced from its previous structure of

```
{
   inputText: {text: ""}
}
```

Causing you the error

Since you are using `inputText.text` to set value of input filed you must initialise the state also in that manner

```
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState({
   text: ""
}); // initialise as an object

function handleChange(event){
    setInputText({ text: event.target.value }); // update the state object with text field
}

function handleClick(event) {
    props.onSubmit(inputText);
    setInputText({text: ""});
    event.preventDefault();
}

return(
         <div className="input-group w-50">
            <input 
                type="text" 
                className="form-control" 
                onChange={handleChange} 
                ariadescribedby="button-addon" 
                value={inputText.text} 
                placeholder="Insert Item">
            </input>
        <div className="input-group-append">
            <Button
                id="button-addon"
                color="dark"
                style={{marginBottom: "2rem"}} 
                onClick={handleClick}>Add Item
            </Button>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```